# MySQL JOIN 2 Sub queries that are dependant upon the 1st sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have been at this most of the day and in an effort to 'get somewhere' today I've started to split down the queries into chunks so that I can stick them together so-to-speak. I've got the 1st query to function as i need (using a join and a subquery) I just need to work out how to do a similar thing to include the result of the 2nd query into a column in Query 1

Query 1:

```
SELECT
u.user_id,
u.firstname,
u.surname,
d.vehicleID,
vehicle.REG
FROM
users AS u
LEFT JOIN vehicle_drivers AS d ON u.user_id = d.driverID AND d.`timestamp` = (SELECT MAX(d2.`timestamp`)
                         FROM vehicle_drivers d2
                         WHERE d2.driverID = u.user_id
                        )
LEFT JOIN vehicle ON d.vehicleID = vehicle.ID
WHERE
    u.hide <> 1
AND remote_logon = 1
```

I then need the result from Query 2:

```
SELECT
    a.referance AS storeID,
FROM
    qrTag_linktable a
INNER JOIN qrTag_linktable AS b ON b.tagID = a.tagID WHERE a.module = 1 and  b.referance = ****d.vehicleID****
```

Here is the qrTag_linktable

```
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
| ID | tagID | module | referance |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
|  3 |     1 |      1 |         1 |
|  8 |     1 |      2 |        67 |
|  9 |    11 |      1 |         4 |
| 10 |    11 |      2 |        77 |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
```

The result (storeID) from Query2 needs to be in a column in Query 1 Query 2 needs the value from d.vehicleID to work. I know i can't be that far away and i've been playing about with sub querys however I just can's seem to get it together! I should also mention that query one may return a NULL result, this is OK, so needs to be a LEFT Join (?)

EDIT 2:
Here is an example if the required results:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
| user_id | firstname | surname | vehicleID | storeID |   REG    |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
|       2 | Steve     | Jobs    |        67 |       1 | VN64 *** |
|     653 | James     | Smith   |        77 |       4 | *** EUF  |
|     592 | Harry     | Potter  |        72 |         | YM64 *** |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

EDIT:
This is my working so far :S

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.firstname,
    u.surname,
    d.vehicleID,
    s.storeID,
    vehicle.REG
FROM
    users AS u
LEFT JOIN vehicle_drivers AS d ON u.user_id = d.driverID
AND d.`timestamp` = (
    SELECT
        MAX(d2.`timestamp`)
    FROM
        vehicle_drivers d2
    WHERE
        d2.driverID = u.user_id
)
LEFT JOIN vehicle ON d.vehicleID = vehicle.ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.referance AS storeID,
        b.referance AS vehicleID
    FROM
        qrTag_linktable a
    INNER JOIN qrTag_linktable AS b ON b.tagID = a.tagID
    WHERE
        a.module = 1
    AND b.referance = d.vehicleID
) AS s ON s.vehicleID = d.vehicleID
WHERE
    u.hide <> 1
AND remote_logon = 1
```

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'd.vehicleID' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Posting a broken query without explanation what you want to do will not help you help us.  Table structure?  Sample input?  Expected output?

Comment: Hi Eric, the broken query is just my work in progress, The rest of the post gives a description of what i want to do. I've added the qrTag_linktable structure i will add an example output.

Comment: The query is fine.  Your explanation needs work.  No one can help you if no one can understand you.  What's the reason for all those joins?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the data I need (example result added) into one result from multiple tables so that the application can produce a single JSON string with the data. I could possibly do it with PHP however i'm trying to leverage SQL more in my work.

Comment: Since you didnt provide an sql fiddle or more information I cannot be sure but I think you should just remove this line `AND b.referance = d.vehicleID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `WHERE` condition `AND b.referance = d.vehicleID` which is redundant since it is being handled in `JOIN` clause `ON s.vehicleID = d.vehicleID`. Notice you alias *b.reference* as *s.vechicleID*.

---

By the way, if using MySQL 8+, consider [CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) for readability which turns your first subquery into a join on aggregate query. `WITH` this approach, everything is referenced as top level named sources without nested `SELECT` statements.

```
WITH max_time AS (
    SELECT driverID,
           MAX(d2.`timestamp`) AS max_time
    FROM vehicle_drivers
    GROUP BY driverID
), 
    tag_link AS (
    SELECT a.referance AS storeID,
           b.referance AS vehicleID
    FROM qrTag_linktable a
    INNER JOIN qrTag_linktable AS b 
        ON b.tagID = a.tagID
    WHERE a.module = 1
)

SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.firstname,
    u.surname,
    d.vehicleID,
    s.storeID,
    v.REG
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN vehicle_drivers AS d 
    ON u.user_id = d.driverID
LEFT JOIN max_time AS m 
    ON u.user_id = m.driverID 
    AND d.`timestamp` = m.max_time
LEFT JOIN vehicle v 
    ON d.vehicleID = v.ID
LEFT JOIN tag_link s 
    ON s.vehicleID = d.vehicleID
WHERE u.hide <> 1
AND remote_logon = 1
```

Comment: thanks, i knew i couldn't have been far off, here's the working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afff33/1

Comment: Great to hear. And here is an update fiddle turning the correlated subquery to a join on aggregate query (more efficient): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afff33/5/0. Again, with MySQL 8.0+ (if you ever migrate to it) you can turn subqueries into CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here:

```
 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            a.referance AS storeID,
            b.referance AS vehicleID
        FROM
            qrTag_linktable a
        INNER JOIN qrTag_linktable AS b ON b.tagID = a.tagID
        WHERE
            a.module = 1
        AND b.referance = d.vehicleID
    ) AS s ON s.vehicleID = d.vehicleID
```

You are using an alias  "d.vehicleID"   that is on the outside in a subquery:

WHERE
        a.module = 1
    AND b.referance = d.vehicleID

Comment: Please do not answer a second time unless answer substantively differ. Simply edit your first question.